# Defining functions of a singleton

Tags: functions

Normally when defining a function we say:

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a function defined by $x \mapsto y$, $x\in X, y\in Y$

My question is if I’m defining a function from a singleton do I write:

$f:\{1\}\rightarrow Y$ defined by $x \mapsto y $ , $x\in X, y\in Y$

Or

$f:\{1\}\rightarrow Y$ defined by $1 \mapsto y $ , $y \in Y$

I just want to make sure I’m defining my functions correctly

Comment: well the function can only take a singleton to a singleton. I personally think the second is clearer because you are only looking at one element.

Comment: If $Y$ is not a singleton then we might break the rule of function. $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by $t \mapsto t+2$

Answer (score 1):

A singleton is a set with only one element. Remember that the domain, range and image of a function are sets, so it doesn't make sense to write $f: 1 \to Y$. If $\{x\}$ is a singleton, you should write $f: \{x\} \to Y$ so that $x \mapsto y=f(x)$.

Comment: I fixed this. Is option 1 or 2 the best option?

Comment: Option 2 is better. But note that $\{1\}$ is a particular singleton with $1$ as element. If you want a more general singleton, say, where $x \in X$ for an abstract set $X$, you should write $\{x\}$ and then $f:\{x\}\to Y$, $x\mapsto y=f(x)$. If you write $f:\{1\}\to Y$ your domain is the element $1$ alone, so the map should read $1 \mapsto y=f(1)$, because your $x$ is $1$.